# using category_encoders.TargetEncoder() on unseen data points

Tags: python

Normally I would instantiate a TargetEncoder in this manner:

```
encoder = TargetEncoder()
X[cat_features] = encoder.fit_transform(X[cat_features],y)
X.head()
```

Then I would perform my train-test-split, and all my X variables (X_train / X_test) would be properly encoded and I can test the performance of my model, which is great!

However, I'm not understanding how I would take this a step further and use it on an 'unseen' sample. Say that I test my model, I think it works, and then someone hands me new observations to make predictions upon. How would I do that without a y of some sort? it appears that all TargetEncoder methods require a y variable. I tried using:

```
valset[cat_features] = encoder.transform(valset[cat_features])
```

but got the error:

```
ValueError: Must train encoder before it can be used to transform data.
```

I tried googling the value error but nothing that looked helpful popped up.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using plain Target Encoder , try taking a look at NestedCVWrapper since this can help avoid target leakage issues and allow proper treatment when there is significant difference between the distributions of categorical variables in train / test sets.

NestedCVWrapper throws the same error when I tried using `transform` but I found out that the `fit_transform` method can receive both the training and validation sets at the same time and thus, you will have 2 objects returned. If you want to see this implementation, take a look at this link: https://contrib.scikit-learn.org/category_encoders/_modules/category_encoders/wrapper.html#NestedCVWrapper.fit_transform